# Execute local python script including local functions on a remote machine without scp

Tags: python, function, ssh, local

I have a python script I currently run on a remote machine with

```
ssh name@server python <~/test/main.py
```

I would like to include functions from my local 'test' directory so I have something similar to this

```
#test/function.py
def my_function():
    return 5

#test/main.py
from function import my_function
print my_function()
```

If I execute my script as usual I get the error

*ImportError: No module named function*

How do I import my local functions to the remote machine?
I don't have permission to save anything on the remote machine so I can't copy my functions with scp.

I have tried to include the path without luck.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '<~/test')
```

Comment: "How do I import my local functions to the remote machine?" You copy the files to the remote machine. You say you can't do that, so guess you're out of luck.

Comment: Perhaps a relative import? `from .function import my_function`. See PEP 328 on relative imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With RPC you can do that, by example [Nameko](https://github.com/onefinestay/nameko) is a framework that help you with that work.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the permission to save anything, then you cannot change anything on the remote machine.

Therefore, if there is nothing there on the remote machine can get you code or functions and make them run, then you are out of luck.